# How to obtain all the hits in elasticsearch for python?

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I am currently trying to run a query using a python package for elasticsearch. However, whenever I call es.search(), I only get 10 results, when there should be more than 1M. Can anyone tell me how I can obtain all the hits?

Comment: The default size for returned document is 10, you need to specify size parameter for setting the returned doc siz

Comment: I tried to set size to 1M, but it threw an error, saying it can't be bigger than 10k.

Comment: So you can give a look to scrool api: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-scroll.html

Comment: How can I do it in Python?

Comment: Check: http://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/helpers.html#scan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `elasticsearch` and `elasticsearch-dsl` libraries:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from elasticsearch_dsl import Search

client = Elasticsearch(host="localhost")

s = Search(using=client, index="my_index")

for hit in s.scan():
    print(hit.title)
```

See the [documentation about pagination](https://elasticsearch-dsl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/search_dsl.html#pagination).